# Postal-code validator for all countries in the world in Java

Tags: java, postal-code

Want solution in Java which does the following:

Input :

1. **Locale code** (Example: **"en_US")**
2. **Postal code**(Example: **"NH 3301"**) --> Valid

Similarly for any other country in the World, it should validate the corresponding Postal code.

Is there any Library for accomplishing this?

Comment: Please let me know the reason for down vote!! so that can take care next time :)

Comment: [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) has a Java client; it might be what you're looking for

Comment: I guess the downvote is because this question [is asking for a library](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Oh!! Will go through help center, before posting next question. Thank you @Uooo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for **[GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/)** . 
It provides us geographical database containing **millions of placeholders** and it covers almost all countries. 
Hope this helps.
Comment if further help is required.

Comment: A simple link is not considered an answer in SO.